# How can i whitelist one specific device using udev rule and block everything else?

Tags: 20.04, usb, security, touchscreen, udev

I want to **whitelist a USB Touch screen** and **block everything else.** I have written hundreds of UDEV rules but none of them seem to work. I can block every single connected USB device but **can't find a way to whitelist one single USB** i.e the monitor. I have tried to match every single attribute of the USB E.G vendorId, productId, manufacturer, serial no etc. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Below you can find some rules that i tried.

**Method 1:**

```
# Block MTP Devices
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"

# Block USB
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb|usbmisc", ATTRS{idVendor}!="0000", ATTRS{idProduct}!="0000", MODE="0000"

# Block USB storage devices
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{removable}=="1", ATTRS{serial}!="", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", MODE="0000"


# Whitelist touch screen
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="03", ATTR{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00", MODE="0666"   # Human Interface Device
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="0e", MODE="0666"    # Video device (monitor)
```

**Method 2:**

```
    # Disable all other USB devices
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'""

# Hub
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{manufacturer}=="Logitech", ATTR{product}=="USB Optical Mouse", ATTR{idVendor}=="046d", ATTR{idProduct}=="c077", ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="00", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'", GOTO="usb_end"
```

Nothing works, setting MODE or setting authorized = 1.

***Note:** You can consider the USB Optical Mouse as my test device i can later replace it with touchscreen attributes.

Please help me set a perfect rule for this and thank you in advance.